# Why is there no re-render after login?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web

When the user logs in, the toolbar items (created with Vuetify) do not change. I am using Vuex to set and get the token required to check whether the user logged in or not. The token is stored in localStorage (for the sake of simplicity).

I am using computed property to check for the token existence in the Toolbar component. But I can't figure out how to change the Toolbar items to the ones specified with `v-if`.

When user logs in, the toolbar items stay the same (I think because Vue tries to be as efficient as possible and doesn't render the toolbar again). But how can I overcome this?

Toolbar component:

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar-items v-if="userLoginStatus">
    <v-btn text :to="'/'" v-on:click="logout" v-on:click.prevent>
      <v-icon left>fas fa-sign-out-alt</v-icon>Sign out
    </v-btn>
  </v-toolbar-items>
  <v-toolbar-items v-else>
    <v-btn text v-else :to="'/login'" v-on:click.prevent :width="123">Login</v-btn>
    <v-btn text v-else :to="'/register'" v-on:click.prevent :width="123">Register</v-btn>
  </v-toolbar-items>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Toolbar',
  computed: {
    userLoginStatus() {
      return this.$store.getters['user/isLoggedIn']
    },
  },
  methods: {
    logout() {
      let conf = confirm('Sure you want to logout?')
      if (conf === true) {
        this.$store.commit('user/logout')
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Login component:

```
<template>
  <v-container fill-height>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-form ref="form">
          <v-text-field v-model="email" label="E-mail" required></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field label="Password" v-model="password" required></v-text-field>
        </v-form>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn depressed color="primary" @click="login">Log in</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Login',
  data: () => {
    return {
      password: '',
      email: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.$axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/login',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        },
      })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            this.$store.commit('user/credentialsSetter', {
              username: resp.data.username,
              loggedIn: true,
              email: this.email,
              token: resp.data.token,
            })

            this.$router.push('/')
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.response) {
            console.log(error.response.data)
            console.log(error.response.status)
            console.log(error.response.headers)
          }
        })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

I have changed the naming of getToken to isLoggedIn so now it is .getters['user/isLoggedIn']. I also changed the .then() section of the axios post of the login.

user store:

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
     .../
     loggedIn: localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') || false,
     .../
    },
    mutations: {
      .../
      credentialsSetter: (state, payload) => {
         localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', payload.loggedIn);
      }
      .../
    },
    getters: {
        isLoggedIn(state) {
            return state.loggedIn;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, so I managed to solve it by setting the states manually

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
     .../
     loggedIn: localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') || false,
     .../
    },
    mutations: {
      .../
      credentialsSetter: (state, payload) => {
         localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', payload.loggedIn);
         state.loggedIn = payload.loggedIn
      },
      logout: (state) => {
            localStorage.clear();
            state.loggedIn = false;
      }
      .../
    },
    getters: {
        isLoggedIn(state) {
            return state.loggedIn;
        }
    }
}
```

**BUT** is there a better way of doing this instead of me setting the values manually to make the state reactive?

Comment: Change your `userLoginStatus()` computed property to method by moving it in `methods` object.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood That doesn't work either

Comment: What's your implementation for `this.$store.getters['user/getToken'];` ? You might not get the expected results because the way you're computing this getter does not include reactive data. If you're implementation is similar to: `return localStorage.getItem('crtUser').token`, it shouldn't work as vue is not watching `localStorage` for changes.

Comment: Can you provide your store?